# Airflow macros to create dynamic argument for Operator

Tags: airflow

What I'm trying to do is use the dag_id and run_id as parts of the path in S3 that I want to land the data, but I'm starting to understand that these templated values are only applied in a task execution context.

Is there anyway that I can provide their values to the Operator like below to control where the files go?

```
my_task = RedshiftToS3Transfer(
  task_id='my_task',
  schema='public',
  table='my_table',
  s3_bucket='bucket',
  s3_key='foo/bar/{{ dag_id }}/{{ run_id }}',
  redshift_conn_id='MY_CONN',
  aws_conn_id='AWS_DEFAULT',
  dag=dag
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a two part answer.

### **FIRST PART:**

How to get get `s3_key` templated.

**Recommended approach:**

Your code will be templated just fine if you import the operator from [providers](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-amazon/). This is because the `RedshiftToS3Transfer` in providers has `s3_key` listed as templated field.

**Deprecated approach:** (Will not be valid for Airflow > 2.0)

Importing the operator from Airflow core you will need to write a custom operator that wraps `RedshiftToS3Transfer` as:

```
from airflow.operators.redshift_to_s3_operator import RedshiftToS3Transfer

class MyRedshiftToS3Transfer (RedshiftToS3Transfer):

    template_fields = ['s3_key']

my_task = MyRedshiftToS3Transfer(
  task_id='my_task',
  schema='public',
  table='my_table',
  s3_bucket='bucket',
  s3_key='foo/bar/{{ dag_id }}/{{ run_id }}',
  redshift_conn_id='MY_CONN',
  aws_conn_id='AWS_DEFAULT',
  dag=dag
)
```

Which will give you:

[image]

### **Second PART:**

How to choose the templated value.
Now as you can see in the first part the output isn't a real working path as it contains invalid values.
I would recommend using task_instance_key_str from the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros-ref.html) it's a unique, human-readable key to the task instance formatted as `{dag_id}__{task_id}__{ds_nodash}`

So you can use it in you code:

```
  s3_key='foo/bar/{{ task_instance_key_str }}'
```

Which will give you:

[image]

That's good for daily DAGs but if your DAG runs on smaller interval you can do:

```
  s3_key='foo/bar/{{task.dag_id}}__{{task.task_id}}__{{ ts_nodash }}'
```

Which will give you:

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks. I ended up getting it working with:

```
class TemplatedRedshiftToS3Transfer(RedshiftToS3Transfer):
    template_fields = ['s3_key']

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

You say that the RedshiftToS3 operator already has template_fields but when I check it directly `RedshiftToS3Transfer.template_field` it is empty tuple. 

using Airflow 1.10.12 fyi

but deriving a new operator from RsToS3 and giving it `s3_key` as templated_field works

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing

```
class TemplatedRedshiftToS3Transfer(RedshiftToS3Transfer):
    template_fields = ['s3_key']

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

to create a new derived class from RedshiftToS3Transfer which passes the `s3_key` field from instantiation through the templating engine